# ClearCanvas DicomFile.DataSet -- How to add a new Tag?

Tags: dicom, clearcanvas

im trying to add a new tag to my DicomFile.DataSet in ClearCanvas.

I notice there is the method "DicomFile.DataSet.RemoveAttribute" but no "AddAtribute" method. So I have been looking at the method "LoadDicomFields" & "SaveDicomFields" but so far can't seem to get them to work. Ive tried to pass in a "DicomFieldAttribute" to these methods, but to no avail.

What am I missing here? Or what do I need to do to add a new tag to the DataSet.

```
DicomFieldAttribute c = new DicomFieldAttribute(tag);
List<DicomFieldAttribute> cs = new List<DicomFieldAttribute>();
cs.Add(c);
DicomFile.DataSet.LoadDicomFields(cs);
DicomFile.DataSet.SaveDicomFields(cs);
if(DicomFile.DataSet.Contains(tag))
{
   tag = 0; //BreakPoint never reached here
}
```

Or I tried this as well::

```
DicomFieldAttribute c = new DicomFieldAttribute(tag);
DicomFile.DataSet.LoadDicomFields(c);
DicomFile.DataSet.SaveDicomFields(c);
if(DicomFile.DataSet.Contains(tag))
{
   tag = 0; //BreakPoint never reached here
}
```

Ive been stuck on what would seem to be a trivial task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing a bit the use of attributes.  The DicomFiledAttribute is a .NET attribute that can be placed on members of a class so that the class is automatically populated with values from a DicomAttributeCollection or or to have the class automatically populated with values from the DicomAttribute Collection.  Ie, given a test class like this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    [DicomField(DicomTags.SopClassUid, DefaultValue = DicomFieldDefault.Default)]
    public DicomUid SopClassUid = null;

    [DicomField(DicomTags.SopInstanceUid, DefaultValue = DicomFieldDefault.Default)]
    public DicomUid SOPInstanceUID = null;

    [DicomField(DicomTags.StudyDate, DefaultValue = DicomFieldDefault.Default)]
    public DateTime StudyDate;
}
```

You could populate an instance of the class like this:

```
DicomFile file = new DicomFile("filename.dcm");
file.Load();
TestClass testInstance = new TestClass();

file.DataSet.LoadDicomFields(testInstance);
// testInstance should now be populated with the values from file
```

If you're interested in just populating some DICOM tags, the DicomAttributeCollection has an indexer in it.  The indexer will automatically create a DicomAttribute instance if it doesn't already exist, for the tag requested via the indexer.  So, to populate a value, you can do soemthing like this:

```
DicomFile file = new DicomFile("filename.dcm");

file.DataSet[DicomTags.SopInstanceUid].SetStringValue("1.1.1");
```

If you want to create the DicomAttribute yourself, you can do something like this:

```
DicomAttribute attrib = new DicomAttributeUI(DicomTags.SopInstanceUid);
attrib.SetStringValue("1.1.1");

DicomFile file = new DicomFile("filename.dcm");
file.DataSet[DicomTags.SopInstanceUid] = attrib;
```

Comment: "file.DataSet[DicomTags.SopInstanceUid].SetStringValue("1.1.1");" Works fine, but when I try something like:: "file.DataSet[1610690560].SetStringValue("1.1.1");" it throws the err (Invalid tag: 60013000). Also the reason i'm doing this is because I want to add a new Overlay(60xx). I notice there is no method like "SetByteArrayValue" that I can use to set the new Overlay data in, which is an array of bytes. Tnx for the answer btw.

Comment: 60013000 is considered a private tag, since its an odd group.  There is a different form of the indexer that uses a DicomTag object.  You may have to create a DicomTag object for the tag you want and use that to access the indexer.